# Java pseudocode to code

Tags: java, pseudocode

I'm about to build a program written in Java. I've already done its pseudocode, but I'm stuck on the code and I don't know what to do exactly. Well this is my progress so far:

pseudocode:

```
class Customer
    Print out “Enter costumer’s name” (Pop up to answer)
    Random boolean 
    If True
      print membership type
      print current date and time
class Visit
    Print out "Have you bought anything?" (Pop up to answer) 
    if the answer is “no”
        print “Have a nice day!”
        exit program
    if else the answer is “yes”
        continue
    if else the answer is not “no” nor “yes”
        ask again
class Discount
    Print "Enter Price of Item:" (Pop up to price)
        if customer's membership type is “Premium”
            the discount to the price will be 20%
        else if customer's membership type is “Gold”
            the discount to the price will be 15%
        else if customer's membership type is “Silver”
            the discount to the price will be 10%
        else if customer's membership type “simple”
            the discount to the price will be 10%
class Main
  Variables: customer, visit, discount
  customer = new object
  Customer visit = new object
Visit discount = new object Discount
  do work with customer
  do work with visit
  do work with discount
    Print customer.name, customer.surname, discount.price, discount.final_price
```

code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Discount
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String cust_name;
        String cust_surname;
        String answer;
        String answer2;

        float firstPrice, rate_1, D_rate, discount, final_price, prem_disc;
        prem_disc = 0;
        final_price = 0;
        discount = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Costumer's Name:");
        cust_name = in.next();
        cust_surname = in.next();

        System.out.println("Have you bought anything?");
        answer = in.next();
        if (answer.equals("no"))
        {
            System.out.println("Have a good day!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (!answer.equals("no"))

            System.out.println("Enter Price of Item:");
        firstPrice = in.nextFloat();

        System.out
                .println("What type of membership do you have? Premium, Gold, Silver or simple?");
        answer2 = in.next();
        if (answer2.equals("Premium"))
        {
            prem_disc = 20;
            discount = (firstPrice * 20 / 100);
            final_price = (firstPrice - discount);
        } else if (answer2.equals("Gold"))
        {
            prem_disc = 15;
            discount = (firstPrice * 15 / 100);
            final_price = (firstPrice - discount);
        } else if (answer2.equals("Silver"))
        {
            prem_disc = 10;
            discount = (firstPrice * 10 / 100);
            final_price = (firstPrice - discount);
        } else if (answer2.equals("simple"))
        {
            prem_disc = 10;
            discount = (firstPrice * 10 / 100);
            final_price = (firstPrice - discount);
        }

        System.out.println("Costumer Name:" + cust_name + " " + cust_surname
                + "\n" + "Discount Rate:" + prem_disc + "\n"
                + "Discounted Price:" + final_price + "\n");

    }
}
```

It's working, but there are many things that are missing. :/

Comment: What **specific** thing(s) are missing?

Comment: I don't see the classes you defined in your pseudo code, e.g. there is no class `Customer` which contains the described functionality. I'd start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take one step at a time, and when that step *completely* works, proceed to the next step.

An example:

Here's your pseudo-code (which, by the way, is a great way to start):

```
class Visit
   Print out "Have you bought anything?" (Pop up to answer)
   if the answer is “no”
       print “Have a nice day!”
       exit program
   if else the answer is “yes”
       continue
   if else the answer is not “no” nor “yes”
       ask again
```

Let's just implement and test the "is the answer yes-or-no" functionality:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java MyHomeworkMainClass}</P>
 **/
public class MyHomeworkMainClass  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      System.out.println("Visit.isUserInputYesNo(null)=" + Visit.isUserInputYesNo(null));
      System.out.println("Visit.isUserInputYesNo(\"gibberish\")=" + Visit.isUserInputYesNo("gibberish"));
      System.out.println("Visit.isUserInputYesNo(\"yes\")=" + Visit.isUserInputYesNo("yes"));
      System.out.println("Visit.isUserInputYesNo(\"no\")=" + Visit.isUserInputYesNo("no"));
   }
}
 class Visit  {
   public static final boolean isUserInputYesNo(String input)  {
      return  (input != null  &&
         (input.equals("yes")  ||  input.equals("no")));
   }
}
```

Now run it and see if it does what you want:

```
[C:\java_code\]java MyHomeworkMainClass
Visit.isUserInputYesNo(null)=false
Visit.isUserInputYesNo("gibberish")=false
Visit.isUserInputYesNo("yes")=true
Visit.isUserInputYesNo("no")=true
```

It does. Now add something else small to this and just keep going until you're done. For particularly difficult parts, it may be beneficial to create a completely separate class, with its own testing class. Then at the end, merge it all together. And *never* get rid of your testing functions, which will always be there for diagnosing future problems.

Good luck!